# Are there any add-ons/extensions that would let me F12 stored procedures in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Basically we use alot of stored procedures, and I would like to be able to quickly navigate to them. Are there any extensions that let me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ctrl+, with the stored procedure name to do a quick smart find.

Comment: So its just double click the SP name, press Ctrl+C and press Ctrl+, it automatically fils your selection and starts searching.

Comment: I think he's wanting to see the definition of the stored procedure, rather than the places in which it's called

Comment: Yes, it will go to the definition not the references.